# Nicer way to test that exactly one flag is set

Tags: conditionals

I have a package that takes a long list of boolean flags (currently about 10) in its options, and I want to test if *exactly* one of these is set to true - something like an XOR for 10+ booleans.

The only way I can think of is to use the `ifthen` package and construct a gigantic statement combining `\and` and `\or` to test this, but it quickly gets real ugly, and will be incredibly hard to maintain.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If one and only one of the flags should be set to true, then you probably shouldn't be using 10 booleans, but a key that can take 10 values...

Comment: That's not an xor. An xor for a bunch of booleans tests whether an odd number of the booleans is true.

Comment: @Tomas: So you want to _test_ if exactly one is true, right? Then it might be worth rewording the question.

Comment: Concatenate the booleans into a 10-digit binary number and then check if it is a power of 2. Easy.

Comment: @Tomas: I've slightly reworded the body of your question; OK?

Comment: @Hendrik: Sure. However, since I'm going to throw an error if the condition is not met, I don't think "make sure" is less accurate than "test if". But if you think it makes a difference, be my guest...

Comment: @Tomas: So then you rather want to _make sure_, and I'd agree with Willie that you'd better use a key. Is there a particular reason why you don't want to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could create a counter, add one for each boolean that is true, then test if the counter has the value 1.

Answer (score 0):

The question does not provide adequate information to provide an 
*exact* routine and as Willie Wong commented, it maybe trying to solve the
problem with the wrong datastructure.

One approach is to place the booleans in a variable consisting
of zeroes and ones. If anyone of the booleans is true then it will then 
be a number that is greater than zero.

```
\def\OneTrue#1{\ifnum#1<1 0\fi\number#1}

\OneTrue{1000101010}
```

One limitation of the macro above is that if the first boolean is 1 then the string can
only be ten digits long, otherwise the number will be too big. Depending on the number of booleans
one could extend the macro and split it into two to avoid this limitation and parse the two arguments.

What one does with it afterwards, it depends. One can actually use the first
boolean that is true to trigger another action. In such a case we would 
have re-discovered the switch datastructure which is catered by `ifcase` in TeX!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with your `\OneTrue` macro. Do you want to test if _at least_ one of the booleans is true? That's not what the OP wants.

Comment: @Hendrik that is exactly what he asked quoting `...I want to test if exactly one of these is set to true'. Have I missed something?

Comment: compare "at least one" with "exactly one".